# cross domain ajax testing in local environment

Tags: javascript, ajax

In local development env.(http://localhost.mydev.com:8081/xapp/x.htm), I need to make an ajax call to open a URL http://hd-ad01.mydev.com:8081/yapp) and paint the response in fancybox.
Since I am in a local dev env, it becomes a cross domain.But when it gets deployed to server, it won't be.
Can someone suggest me, how to test my Ajax call locally using fiddler or some tool?
I tried using fiddler and modified the Response Header to add oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
I followed the complete steps from the blog http://blog.caplin.com/2010/03/19/using-fiddler-to-help-develop-cross-domain-capable-javascript-web-applications/
It didn't work out for me. Can some suggest a solution?

Comment: What you mean by didn't work, what the error was?. Can you just set that Http header on hd-ad01 server and connect to this from local env?

Comment: I am able to set the Access-Cotntrol-Allow-Origin on the Response Header.But I didn't receive any response from server.There is no error at all. From firebug I have seen the response code for the call is 200 OK.But it doesn't have the reponse tab at all.

Comment: You would need to test the service end using something like http://www.getpostman.com/ you will not be able to access the url unless they have CORS enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because fancybox jquery plugin sets the request header
Access-Control-Request-Header as x-fancyBox

This param fails my Cross Domain call though i set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin as * in the response header.

I have commented that default value of headers in the fancybox 2.1.4 source code and tried the same and I am able to make the cross domain ajax call

ajax : {
    dataType : 'html',
    //headers  : { 'X-fancyBox': true }
}

Can someone tell me how to modify the headers value programatically?
I tried the following approaches and it didn't worked out for me

dataType : 'html',
headers  : { 'X-fancyBox': false }

dataType : 'html',
headers  : { }